# How does the Imagick PHP extension locate the ImageMagick library?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

From [the docs](https://github.com/Imagick/imagick#security): "The PHP extension Imagick works by calling the ImageMagick library".

I'm unclear *how* it calls the ImageMagick library. What path/paths does it search, where are those paths configured, and which parts of the ImageMagick install does it actually require?

I'm trying to create a standalone, portable install of PHP (on macOS). I have that working fine with numerous other extensions eg xdebug, ssh2, redis etc but cannot get imagick working. I have it compiled and installed no problem but when I move the PHP install to a clean machine, `phpinfo()` lists `ImageMagick number of supported formats 0`.

Comment: Have you seen the top comment on this page? https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php#94169 It is 14 years old, but it might point you in a direction at least

Comment: The link is made in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell please correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're referring to the php.ini entry that enables the imagick.so extension, not some means of telling imagick.so where ImageMagick is installed.

Answer (score 1):

All the work for configuring where ImageMagick is located is done at the 'configure' step when compiling the Imagick extension.

If you're compiling Imagick yourself, you have some control over that as you can pass the location of where to look for ImageMagick headers and C files with the `--with-imagick` parameter e.g.

```
./configure --with-imagick=/usr/im6
```

Otherwise the compiler will try to find ImageMagick using the program `pkg-config`.

If you're installing Imagick through a package manager, where Imagick looks for the ImageMagick files is outside of your control as that is done by whoever is managing that package manager.

btw it is possible to compile both the Imagick and ImageMagick libaries statically as code with PHP, however that might not work as well as you hope, as ImageMagick itself tends to install quite a few files on the computer, some of which are editable to control how ImageMagick works.

For a docker container I was using, I had to copy the following files across.

```
/usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.12/config-Q16/configure.xml 

/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.a 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.7 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.7.0.0 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.a
/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.la
/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.7
/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.7.0.0

/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ImageMagick-6.Q16.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore-6.Q16.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickWand-6.Q16.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickWand.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/Wand-6.Q16.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/Wand.pc

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpmux.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpdemux.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1

/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/coder.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/colors.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/log.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/magic.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/mime.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/quantization-table.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/thresholds.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-apple.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-dejavu.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-ghostscript.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-urw-base35.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-windows.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/type.xml
```

That list was found using the tool 'strace' and seeing what files ImageMagick was failing to find when it errored.

There are some other projects trying to make it possible to make installable PHP programs. It might be worth teaming up with them for this kind of stuff.